# What parameters does the post to Twitter url accept?

Tags: twitter

I am using the url "http://twitter.com/?status=Some Status" to allow a user to post a tweet from my site. I was wondering if there are any other parameters it accepts other than status? For one I would like a callback url so it can return back to my site or notify my site of the tweet. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visit https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents for a complete list of paramters.

If you use the Tweet Button code (link's in the page above), the default behaviour should open a new window for the user to tweet, so you shouldn't have to worry about wrangling them back to your website, as they can just close the pop-up window after they tweet.

If you want some sort of callback operation, you will have to use [Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/) and develop your own way of handling the tweeting process. Or, check and see if other sites/apps have any pre-built tools you can use.

Comment: This is not helpful or correct. The person is looking for "text" and "url" and "tags" etc.